# How to create association records using sequelize typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have trouble in understanding how to query the associations.

**Here is the index.ts of Model:**

```
import { DataTypes, ModelStatic, Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { WhisperInstance, Whisper } from "./whisper.js";
import { UserInstance, User } from "./user.js";

export interface AssociateInterface {
  associate?: (model: ModelsInterface) => void;
}

export interface ModelsInterface {
  [key: string]: ModelStatic<WhisperInstance | UserInstance> &
    AssociateInterface;
}

export type EnvironmentTypes = "dev" | "prod";

const env: EnvironmentTypes =
  (process.env.NODE_ENV as EnvironmentTypes) || "dev";

import { dbConfig } from "../config/config.js";
const config: any = dbConfig[env];

// Open database connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
  }
);

const modelInitializers = [Whisper, User];
const models: ModelsInterface = {};

// Initialize each model in the database
// This must be done before associations are made

modelInitializers.forEach(
  (modelInitializer) =>
    (models[modelInitializer.name] = modelInitializer(sequelize, DataTypes))
);

// Add associations

Object.entries(models).map(([_modelName, model]) => {
  if (model?.associate) {
    model.associate(models);
  }
});

// });

// Create database tables
sequelize.sync();

export { sequelize as database, models }; //exporting db
```

**user.ts**

```
import { Sequelize, Model, ModelStatic, NonAttribute } from "sequelize";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { AssociateInterface, ModelsInterface } from "./index.js";
import { WhisperInstance } from "./whisper.js";
// import { WhisperInstance } from "./whisper.js";

export interface UserAttributes {
  userId?: string; //This will be auto generated
  name: string;
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

export interface UserCreationAttributes extends UserAttributes {}

export interface UserInstance
  extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>,
    UserAttributes {
  Whisper?: NonAttribute<WhisperInstance>;
  readonly id: number;
  readonly createdAt: Date;
  readonly updatedAt: Date;
}

export const User = (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: any) => {
  const User: ModelStatic<UserInstance> & AssociateInterface =
    sequelize.define<UserInstance>("User", {
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: uuid().replace(/^.{2}/g, "UR"),
      },
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
    });

  User.associate = (models: ModelsInterface) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Whisper, {
      foreignKey: "whisperId",
      as: "whsipers",
    });
  };

  return User;
};
```

**whisper.ts:**

```
import { Sequelize, Model, ModelStatic } from "sequelize";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { AssociateInterface, ModelsInterface } from "./index.js";

export interface WhisperAttributes {
  data: string;
  whisperId?: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

export interface WhisperCreationAttributes extends WhisperAttributes {}

export interface WhisperInstance
  extends Model<WhisperAttributes, WhisperCreationAttributes>,
    WhisperAttributes {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly createdAt: Date;
  readonly updatedAt: Date;
}

export const Whisper = (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: any) => {
  const Whisper: ModelStatic<WhisperInstance> & AssociateInterface =
    sequelize.define<WhisperInstance>("Whisper", {
      data: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      whisperId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: uuid().replace(/^.{2}/g, "WR"),
      },
    });

  Whisper.associate = (models: ModelsInterface) => {
    Whisper.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "WhisperId" });
  };

  return Whisper;
};
```

Q. How can I create a record?
This is what I did. But I was getting error.

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data, userId } = req.body;
    const resp = await models.Whisper.create(
      {
        data,
        userId,
      },
      {
        include: [models.User],
      }
    );
    respondWith(res, { success: true, ...resp });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    respondWith(res, err, 400);
  }
});
```

I can't find documentation for association (not class based approach). If you can share the documentation / github repo, it would be great! Thanks in advance